# A problem occurred starting process 'command 'scripts/changelog.sh'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle

I'm having an issue in starting process 'command 'scripts/changelog.sh'.
When I try to sync project with gradle file, I get this error.
The problem might be in the path directory.

error image:

[image: Click here to see error image]

Project Structure & build.gradle:

[image: Click here to see error image]

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Wherever relevant, convert your images to text. Also provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).